# Controling alignment in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have a JList with Strings that when put in panel with the default format, as expected, is aligned in the center of the panel. Is there a way to control this alignment with any of the other formats, or something like that?

Comment: No need for further help, but thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to control this alignment

Yes, but you haven't given a specific requirement so we can't give a specific answer.

The default layout for a `JPanel` is the `FlowLayout` with center alignment.

If you want a different layout then you can:

1. change the `FlowLayout` to be either right or left aligned. Read the `FlowLayout` API for the proper parameters
2. change the panel to use a different layout manager. Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for working examples of the other layout managers.

Comment: You gave me enough information so i can find what i was searching for on my own. That's what i needed and that's why i wasn't too specific. But you are propably right saying that this is the reason why i didn't get awnsers. I'll have that in mind next time. Thank you!